# How to handle spaces in text file generated from a XML and XSLT file?

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace, transformation

I have been working on this XML file (more than 460.000 lines) in order to extract all the content tags and store them in a separate text file. 
This XSLT code executed and created the file I desired, but I don't understand why the resulting text file is full of whitespaces even if I used the strip space element in the XSLT file for erasing all the whitespaces not useful.

this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sa>
    <review>
        <product>
            <name> 
                Scary movie
            </name>
        </product>
        <rating> 
            0.5 
        </rating>
        <content>
            bad
        </content>
    </review>
    <review>
        <product>
            <name> 
                The Space 
            </name>
        </product>
        <rating> 
            0.5
        </rating>
        <content>
            bad
        </content>
    </review>
</sa>
```

This is the XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
           <xsl:for-each select="review">
               <xsl:if test="rating=0.5">
                   <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/content"/>
               </xsl:if>   
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result is :

```
bad

bad
```

Why is there this space between the 2 "content" tags?

Comment: Can you show us the result you want? There is lots of white space in your data.

Comment: just 

`code` bad
 bad `code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsl:strip-space only removes text nodes that consist entirely of whitespace. It doesn't trim the leading and trailing whitespace in nodes that also contain printable text, like:

```
            <name> 
                The Space 
            </name>
```

For that, the usual approach is normalize-space():

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ancestor-or-self::*/content)"/>
```

Or rather than inserting calls on normalize space everywhere, you might want to do a preprocessing pass over the document that has an identity template rule plus the rule

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

normalize-space() may do more than you want - it replaces internal sequences of whitespace (including newlines) by a single space. In XSLT 2.0 it's easy enough to write your own trim() function that does something less radical. In XSLT 1.0 that's harder - it requires recursive named templates - so this is definitely something for a preprocessing pass.